# How to design the sql query for intersection between 2 sets of data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2008

i have these tables

```
create table Programs(
Id int identity(1,1) not null,
Days int not null,
Monday bit not null,
Tuesday bit not null,
Wednesday bit not null,
Thursday bit not null,
Friday bit not null,
Saturday bit not null,
Sunday bit not null)

create table ProgramItems(
Id int identity(1,1) not null,
ProgramId int not null,
ItemId int not null
IsActive bit not null)

create table Items(
Id int identity(1,1) not null,
Monday bit not null,
Tuesday bit not null,
Wednesday bit not null,
Thursday bit not null,
Friday bit not null,
Saturday bit not null,
Sunday bit not null)

create table CustomerProgram(
Id int identity(1,1) not null,
CustomerId int not null,
ProgramId int not null,
StartDate datetime not null)
```

when the user will define a program, he should do the following
1- define the program days ( Mon, Tue, Wed, Fri ) for example
2- to select the program items

i want to display all items that match these days in a grid, for example

Items that are available on Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu will be shown in the grid for selection since program days has common with the items days ( Mon, Tue, Wed)

but if item is available for example on (Thu,Sat) should not be shown in the grid.

my problem how to continue this query in sql?

```
select * 
from Items
where Id not in(select ItemId from ProgramItems
where ProgramId=1)
/* here i should pick only items that match with the program days*/
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
declare @program int
set @program=1

select * 
from Items i, Programs p
where not exists(select 1 from ProgramItems where p.Id=ProgramId and i.Id=ItemId) and
      ((p.Monday=1 and i.Monday=p.Monday) or
      (p.Tuesday=1 and i.Tuesday=p.Tuesday) or
      (p.Wednesday=1 and i.Wednesday=p.Wednesday) or
      (p.Thursday=1 and i.Thursday=p.Thursday) or
      (p.Friday=1 and i.Friday=p.Friday) or
      (p.Saturday=1 and i.Saturday=p.Saturday) or
      (p.Sunday=1 and i.Sunday=p.Sunday))
where p.Program=@program
```

here a working [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65d80)

Comment: thank you for the answer, i will try it and return back to you

Answer (score 2):

The following returns items were at least one of `Monday`, `Tuesday`, or `Wednesday` are set:

```
select i.*
from Items i
where Id not in(select ItemId from ProgramItems where ProgramId = 1) and
      (Monday = 1 or Tuesday = 1 or Wednesday = 1);
```

The following returns items where all three days are set:

```
select i.*
from Items i
where Id not in(select ItemId from ProgramItems where ProgramId = 1) and
      (Monday = 1 and Tuesday = 1 and Wednesday = 1);
```

EDIT:

If you have a particular program, you can do:

```
select i.*
from Items i join
     Programs p
     on p.id = @ProgramId and
        (i.Monday >= p.Monday and i.Tuesday >= p.Tuesday and i.Wednesday >= p.Wednesday and
         i.Thursday >= p.Thursday and i.Friday >= p.Friday and
         i.Saturday >= p.Saturday and i.Sunday >= p.Sunday
        )
where not exists (select 1
                  from ProgramItems pi
                  where pi.ProgramId = p.id and pi.ItemId = i.Id);
```

Comment: thank you Gordon, your answer is great if i know previously the days of program as i mentioned in my sample above, but the tables containing 100's or records, so what i am searching for, is a query that i will give me the result based on the different program settings

Comment: @mah . . . But how do you know what those settings are?  Your question is not clear on that point.

Comment: here where i am stuck, i am not able to figure out how to get the items that should appear as candidate list for a particular program, i believe this can be done in sql rather than building the sql statement from the application and send it to sql for execution

Comment: please can you check my other question, some users put it on hold and in my opinion it is clear and not solved yet.

Answer (score 1):

Surely this is just a matter of a simple join?

```
Select I.* FROM Items AS I
INNER JOIN ProgramItems AS PI
ON PI.ItemId = I.Id
INNER JOIN Program AS P
ON P.Id = PI.ProgramID
WHERE (I.Monday = 1 OR I.TuesDat = 1 OR I.WednesDay =1) --you get the picture
AND P.Id = 1
```

But I must question the duplication of the monday-sunday bit fields in the item and program tables: why should it exist in both places? In fact, I'd drop the where (I.day = 1 etc) clause and populate a calendar based on whether the selected values are 1 or 0 in code.

Comment: thank you for the answer, in my query i tried to trim all items that are already included in the program and to retrieve all items that are not included in that particular program, in other words, i am trying to give the user the remaining items that still not used, but i think your answer will give me solution if i know that Monday is 1 or Tuesday is 1 and so on, i have around 100 programs each with different settings, so i need a generic solution

Comment: I see. In that case you can select MAX(I.Monday, P.Monday) as Monday, etc. for each day, joining as I have above and group by the programId, ItemId and any other fields you want to see. Where the MAX is 0 you have an available day. This could be expanded with time slots too if your programs need this.